# error compressing netcdf files using nccopy through a loop

Tags: unix, compression, netcdf

I am trying to compress multiple netcdf files in different folders through a loop.

```
for i in `find . -iname 'wrfout*'`;
do
echo $i
time nccopy -d5 -s $i d_${i}
```

When I run this code, I get an error message
"./wrfout_d04_2011-08-13_00:00:00
Permission denied
Location: file ../../ncdump/nccopy.c; line 1429".
However, when I run the last line in the loop for individual files, it runs without any error messages. I have checked the permission mode for the execution file to "777" just to be sure, but still the error persists. Any help with this is approciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your bash syntax suggests your output filenames are going to look like 'd_./wrfout_d04_2011-08-13_00:00:00'

Suggestion:

```
nccopy -d5 -s $i $(dirname $i)/d_$(basename $i)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. 
The use of the 'find' is recursive, so it goes through all the subdirectories in the original directory to identify and list the files with the basename. Is there a way to write this so that it can separate the basename and append the extra name to distinguish between the original and compresssed files?

Comment: The combination of `dirname` and `basename` should achieve this, in conjunction with your original `find` command, unless I have misunderstood what you are asking. The new file is prepended with `d_` into the same directory.

Comment: @ Robert. The change worked as described. Thanks so much.